# Accessing $_POST variables in PHP from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, post

I've made an android app that sends two strings of latitude and longitude values over HTTP post, which are then taken by PHP code and stored in variables. Those variables should  then, in theory, be taken in by some JavaScript code. However, while I know that the PHP code is getting the strings since I can write them to a different html file, whenever I try to alert() the value of the JavaScript variable where I stored the string, I just get a blank alert. Here is my PHP and JavaScript code. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php
$latitude = $_POST["Latitude"];
$longitude = $_POST["Longitude"];
$dateTime = date('m/d/y h:i:s A');
file_put_contents("locationData.html", $latitude, FILE_APPEND);
?>
<html>
<title>Find My Location</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
  #map-canvas { width: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(My api key removed for privacy)">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var latitude = "<?php echo $latitude?>";
   alert(latitude);
   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.6520, -82.3250),
      zoom:10
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);            
    }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body>
<head><strong>Recent Locations</strong></head>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
```

Comment: sigh. PHP is run server side, Javascript client side. What are you playing at?

Comment: The source of your page in your browser, does it contain the right latitude value in the javascript?

Comment: @thecoshman What do you mean?

Comment: @Gudgip, no, it just contains an empty string.

Comment: try to log it and see by console.log(latitude) and check in browser log ....

Comment: why you mentioned ANDROID tag here??

Comment: @vivek all is logs is ""

Comment: @Allfer2 may be the value that is sent is empty string

Comment: @vivek I know that the value isn't an empty string because when I use file_put_contents() to write it to a different file, I get a value written to that fi;le.

Comment: @Allfer2 just a blind guess try alert(<?php echo $latitude?>) ...

Comment: No idea if it makes any difference, but maybe try `<?php echo $latitude; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above code I do not see any reason why latitude isn't being alerted to the user. But I have made a few changes that I think you should implement to prevent XSS and also error checking. You should really check if the `$_POST` variables exist before using them. This is probably the reason why it's only returning an empty string.

```
<?php
    function latlong_xss_check($value) {
        $value = strip_tags($value);
        if(!is_numeric($value)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $value;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Latitude'],$_POST['Longitude'])) {
        $latitude = latlong_xss_check($_POST['Latitude']);
        $longitude = latlong_xss_check($_POST['Longitude']);
    }else{
        $latitude = 0;
        $longitude = 0;
    }


?>
<script>
    var latitude = "<?php echo $latitude; ?>";
    var longitude = "<?php echo $longitude; ?>";
    alert(latitude + ' : ' + longitude);
</script>
```

Comment: When I add this code the javascript alert always shows the value as 0, no matter how many times I send the post data

Comment: I believe that the $_POST data isn't being sent than. You can add `print_r($_POST);` to the top of the page and see if those values are actually set in $_POST or not.